# Creating a unique file in Google Drive in android

Tags: android, google-drive-api

I'm using the Google Drive Android API (yes I know its still in developer preview), to create a file on Drive that can persist data across all of a user's devices.

https://developers.google.com/drive/android/create-file

So, use the app on your phone:

-Check that the file exists (filter by filename and not in trash)

--If exists then read and update local sqlite with data

--If not exists then create new file, and write data from sqlite. Then request sync.

-When user changes data, open file again, write contents and commit/sync.

I'm finding situations when testing where I run on my phone, and then on my tablet, and there happens to be multiple files created of the same name and my app gets confused when opening. I'm guessing there were duplicates because there was a delay in the sync and the 2nd device didn't find the existing file so created a new one.

So, now I'm thinking, I pull in all files with that name (not marked trash) and merge them, then mark trash on all but one of them and call that the current. This will leave many files in the trash as time passes.

Couple of questions:

1. Is there anyway to create a file with a unique name, or pull by some unique handle. The duplicates are making things a hassle to use this Drive product.
2. Is there anyway to delete a file, not mark for trash, but actually delete. After a merge, I don't want to leave hundreds of files marked for trash on someones drive after months of use.
3. Am I missing something obvious here? All I want to do is continually overwrite a file by the last device to save data and call that the master copy. Then let other devices know that they should refresh when they run. Right now, I have a network tool app, but I'm also creating a game and was hoping to leverage this same mechanism to save/persist game state across devices....at this point I'm not so confident that Drive is the proper means.

Answer (score 5):

As you've discovered title's are not unique in Drive.  However, each item in Drive does have a unique identifier.  In the Android API, the DriveId is the representation of this.  (In the web API its the resource id).

Once you create the file, you can save the DriveId in local preferences so that next time you can just look it up by the ID.  This will guarantee that you will always have the same file on the same device.

On other devices, you can first do a query by title to determine if it exists already, and then save off the DriveId if it does.

Comment: This is an idea. Probably still need to deal with a merge. Just in case.

Answer (score 1):

[Google Play Cloud Save](https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/cloudsave) is designed for lightweight persisting of save state across multiple devices including conflict resolution and was built originally for games (although any app can use it). This seems like a more likely fit for what you want to do than trying to work with the full file system approach that is Google Drive.

Comment: But doesnt this force the user to be part of Google+? I know when I accessing the Play's game features (leaderboards, etc) it forced me to Google+ (which I declined).

Comment: Cloud Save is implemented separately from Google Play Games services and does not require the same level of Google+ integration.

Comment: I'm looking at this now to see if it fits my need. Looks like there are size maximums.

Comment: @Nick - correct. Currently you get four 256kb slots although I would really review your data structure if you need to store over 1MB of information to save game state - that is a lot of text content.

Comment: Agreed, however as I mentioned this is not for a game. It's a network tool app.